# BroadcastReceiver and sharedpreference

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm making an notification by using function called "reciver" extends BroadcastReceiver.
Notification has pendingIntent with A.class.
So Once the notification is clicked, it calls A.class.
Within A.class, it calls the function in MainActivity to use sharedpreference and update the data. But whenever it reaches the sharedpreference, it crashes.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.content.SharedPreferences.getInt(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
```

Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Comment: post some codes, plz

Comment: Where is u r code? post it

Comment: either Your SharedPreferences are null or the Key that You use to get the integer from SharedPreferences..

Answer (score 1):

You have to initiate SharedPreferences first.
Something like that:

```
private PreferencesManager mPreferencesManager;
```

and in onCreate():

```
mPreferencesManager = PreferencesManager.getInstance(this);
```